# Consumir SOAP Service que requiere un certificado digital ( AXIS2 )

Tags: java, webservice, soap, axis

Buenas,
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para consumir servicios SOAP. Estos servicios requieren la firma digital para autenticarse.

Alguien me puede orientar? Como implemento la autenticación usando el fichero de la firma electronica.

He usado Axis2 para generar la clases de java necesarias.

La aplicación es para consumir los servicios nuevos de la hacienda en España.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Los archivos de firma digital se manejan en distintos formatos, tiene que coincidir con los que tu servidor soap te pida.

En Mexico se usan 2 archivos para realizar esto, un archivo .cer que es un certificado digital, y un .key que es un archivo der de clave privada encriptado.

dependiendo el servidor se requieren distintas acciones:

- Firmar una cadena de texto con la clave privada(tambien necesitas saber con que algoritmo firmarlo por ejemplo "SHA-1").
- enviar el archivo en der, y la clave de encriptacion
- enviar el archivo der desencriptado
- convertir el der (desencriptado) a pem (a veces volverlo a encriptar)

Comment: Mi pregunta era sobre la configuraci'on de las llamadas cuando los servicios SOAP esten protegidos por certificados digitales. Gracias de todas maneras.

Comment: voto porque esta respuesta sea eliminada, no responde a la duda y ni siquiera tiene un acercamiento a la cuestión del usuario... Ya que el firmado digital en México no es ligeramente cercano a los procesos en Espa~a, Colombia y Argentina....